# Intel x86 assembly code behavior question

Tags: assembly, intel

I have a Intel assembly x86(16 bit version) assembly code as below which prints the message fine. Using flat assembler to assemble on Win-7 32 bit.

```
ORG 100h
USE16

        mov ah, 09
        mov dx, message
        jmp  Displayit  ;unconditional jump

        mov ah,01
        int 21h

        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h

Displayit:
        int 21h

message db 'Testing assembly jump instruction', 0Ah, '$'
```

1. If I move the string definition of message(in code below), at the beginning, it does not print that string? What is the reason?
2. Also, although I have the instruction `mov ah, 01, int 21h` to keep the output command prompt/console from closing, it does not work. The console just closes before I can see the message is printed or not?

.

```
ORG 100h
USE16
message db 'Testing assembly jump instruction', 0Ah, '$'

mov ah, 09
mov dx, message
jmp  Displayit  ;unconditional jump

mov ah,01
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

Displayit:
    int 21h
```

Comment: What is the first instruction executed by your code in both cases? Why? And at what time does `mov ah, 01`,`int 21h` get executed?

Comment: I guess it would be mov ah,09 wouldn't it ?

Comment: Also even if I put the mov ah,01 code in the Displayit: label, the console closes without waiting on it. And the string gets printed only if message is not at the beginning, but somewhere down. Strange!

Comment: The string is pritned only if it is defined anywhere after the jmp instruction call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you define the string at the beginning, it will be executed as code. This leads to a crash or all kinds of undefined behaviour.
2. The instruction sequence beginning with `mov ah,1` is never executed, you jump over it.

Comment: Even if I put the mov ah,1 code in the jump label DisplayIT:, still the console window just closes without waiting there.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. My bad. now it does wait on the console, when code mov ah,1 is in jump label.